# create global filter functions that all consumes same api and use it in different components -- VUE.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am very much confused about this. Trying to create global filter functions that consumes same api and filter it. Really confused how to achieve. To make myself more clear here an example:

with vuex `getters` I am feeding my `list` and `map` components in home page.

### Code UPDATED

**home** component:

```
<template>
   <list :cars="cars" />
   <map :cars="cars" />
   <filter-component />
</template>


data(){
    return {
        keyword: ""
        price: ""
    };
},
mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch("loadCars");
},
computed: {
    loadApi(){
        return this.$store.getters.loadCars;
    },
    cars(){
        let filter = this.loadApi.filter(textFilter(this.keyword));
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Now I want to filter `cars` getters. But not the local way. Trying to do globally. So I created `mixins/textfilter.js` and `pricefilter.js`  and exporting those...

```
export const textFilter = (text) => (car) => {
if (text > 0) {
    if (
      car.name.match(text) ||
      car.color.match(text)
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

And trying to make event from filter-component to update keyword...

```
<template>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
</template>

export default {
    data(){
        return {

        };
    },
}
```

Now the problem here. How can I handle event (event-bus or etc) and filter the **cars** object in **home.vue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CODESANDBOX example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-4m9c2

this should work...

```js
import { textFilter } from "../../mixins/textFilter.js";
import { priceFilter } from "../../mixins/priceFilter.js";

export default {
  computed: {
    allCars(){
      return this.$store.getters.cars;
    },
    volvos() {
      return this.allCars.filter(textFilter('volvo'));
    }
  }
};
```

just note that you also have some issues in your text filter.

try this curried function instead

```js
export const textFilter = (text) => (car) => {
  if (text.length > 0) {
    if (
      car.name.match(text) ||
      car.color.match(text) ||
      car.price.match(text)
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

---

To make it even *more* globally accessible and unique, you could move the filter into your vuex getter like this:

```js
//  store.js
import { textFilter } from "@/mixins/textFilter.js";
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cars: [
      { name: "Volvo s40", color: '...', price: '...'},
      { name: "Volvo v70r", color: '...', price: '...'},
    ],
    textFilterString: 'volvo'
  },
  getters: {
    filteredCars: state => {
      return state.cars.filter(textFilter(state.textFilterString))
    }
  }
})
```

this will require additional action and methods to manage the `textFilterString` variable, but then you can get the filtered list from anywhere without any duplication or recalculation unless the data or the filter string changes.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but before going in action with the code. I have question for you. how `...mapGetters({
      cars: "cars"
    }),` takes effects on **home.vue**'s cars getters. because I am passing that one. to other components?

Comment: it's the same as `cars(){return this.$store.getters.cars;}`. I should have used that in the example. I'll update the answer.

Comment: okay I guess, i couldn't make myself clear :)) my english is not that good. Anyway in the **home** component you can see I  am passing a **cars** object to another components. I want to filter THAT object from filterCars component. Additionally you can see, i have couple filter functions. So I don't want to re-filter  the cars object everytime, want to update it. I mean i want filter functions are work with together... Normally, I am doing all of this in one component with local filter functions... but now trying to understand this way of using...

Comment: updated answer with example of how to use filter right out of the vuex getter

Comment: With vuex, you typically wouldn't pass the object down to child components as whole, because you can usually just reference it from within, but you could just make another computed in your `home` component and do the filtering there before passing it.

Comment: thank you for the update. I also updated the question. **First**, the exported textFilter function is not working... I mean when I write like this `return this.loadApi.filter(textFilter('volvo')` and give it the text directly. It doesn't filter. But no error aswell. **Second** even if it works. I want to call the event from another component because my text input is in **filter-component**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195167/discussion-between-parabellum-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create `mixins` whenever you want to have some filter which can be easily accessible to any component.

[Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) Learn more about it on Official Docs

You just need to create a mixin say - `filtersMixins.js`. Then `import` it to your component.

In your `mixin` file you can export all the extra `vue instance properties` to your component like `methods`

In `filtersMixins.js`

```
export const myMixin = {
  created: function () {
    this.hello()
  },
  methods: {
    hello: function () {
      console.log('hello from mixin!')
    }
  }
}
```

In your component

```
import { myMixin } from './mixins/filtersMixins'
```

Now in your inside your instance, call it simply

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  mixins: [myMixin]
})
```

Now, In the component you can simply use it like a vue property by referring `this` Like `methods`. You can call mixin methods `hello` by `this.hello()`

Pros - You can write common `methods` in your `mixins` file and you can have the component binded to the `method` means you can use the component `this` to your `mixins methods`

In case you want to have global method which does not need to be `binded` to component.

Create it in same file and simply export it

```
export const globalFilter = str => {
  return str.split('')
}
```

and use it anywhere by

```
import { globalFilter } from './mixins/filtersMixins'
```